# Why is "npm install" removing an unrelated package?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

When I run `npm install --save bootstrap-vue` it removes my fontawesome package that is already installed.

When I run `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` it removes the bootstrap-vue package.

The only way to have both packages installed is to specify them both on the command line like this: `npm install --save bootstrap-vue @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

I thought maybe there was some corruption in my `package-lock.json` file, so I tried nuking that and reinstalling everything, but the behavior persisted.

What gives?  I have never encountered this sort of thing before, where the installation of one package causes another to be removed.

UPDATE: Following is my package.json file, without either package installed. With this as my starting point (and no package-lock.json), I can install either package, but then when I install the other one it deletes the first one.  It doesn't matter what order I use.

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": []
}
```

Edit: Just a note to say that this still persists, three months later.  It's the weirdest darned thing.

Comment: I typed `npm init -y` `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` `npm install --save bootstrap-vue` and both seem to be installed correctly.  So how do I reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Wyck: Beats me.  I just edited the question to include my package.json. Maybe that will help?

Comment: I used your `package.json` but still couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for trying to reproduce it!

Comment: What versions of `npm` and `node` are you running? What operating system? Is there a `yarn.lock` file? (`npm` 7 respects `yarn.lock` files.) Maybe an `npm-shrinkwrap.json`?

Comment: @Trott The npm version is 6.14.10.  Node version is v14.15.4 .  There is no yarn.lock nor npm-shrinkwrap.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this in your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": []
```

With this entry, `dependencies` will not be updated when you install something. Change it to this instead:

```
"dependencies": {}
```